# How to bind to a singleton property in Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

Hi all first post here :)
Let's start with a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
public MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private static MyClass _instance;
  public static MyClass Instance
  {
      get
      {
          if (_instance == null)
              _instance = new MyClass();
          return _instance;
      }
  }

  private bool _myProperty;
  public bool MyProperty
  {
      get
      {
        return _myProperty;
      }
      set
      {
          if (_myProperty!= value)
          {
              _myProperty= value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
          }
      }
   }

   private MyClass() { ... }
}
```

As you can see, it's a singleton class.
In my view, I want to bind a control on MyProperty. My initial idea was to import MyClass as a static ressource in my view using something like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Metrics.Silverlight.ChartView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:logic="clr-namespace:Metrics.Logic;assembly=Metrics.Logic">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <logic:MyClass x:Key="myClass" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

And bind it like so:

```
<Button Margin="5" Click="btnName_Click"  Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource myClass}, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}, Path=MyAttribute, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Of course, this approach won't work since MyClass constructor's is private. I also cannot use x:static since it's not available in Silverlight 4.

I've been stuck on this problem far longer than I should have...
How can I bind on MyProperty?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have your UserControl, internally, expose the MyClass instance through it's own property, and bind locally to it's own "MyClass" instance.  Since it's a Singleton, this will always be the same instance.

Comment: Hi M. Copsey, I'd like to try out your suggestion, but I must admit that I don't quite understand how to approach this. I'm still new to silverlight/xaml programming. I'd appreciate if you could elaborate :)

Comment: @Tigel: This is basically the same as Elad's option listed below.  I was just recommending leaving your singleton alone, but having a property in your control itself (non-static) that returns the singleton.

Comment: Alright problem solved. Thanks for your help gentlemen! @Vladimir Dorokhov @Reed Copsey @Elad Katz

Answer (score 8):

I advice to add additional class `MyClassProvider`:

```
public class MyClassProvider
{
    public MyClass MyClass { get { return MyClass.Instance; } }
}
```

Instance of this class you can place anywhere and bind to its `MyClass` property.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement the singleton *slightly* differently, like so:

```
  private static MyClass _instance;
  public MyClass Instance // note the getter is not static
  {
      get
      {
          if (_instance == null)
              _instance = new MyClass();
          return _instance;
      }
  }
```

so now you could do the following in xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Metrics.Silverlight.ChartView"
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <logic:MyClass x:Key="myClass" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

and bind it like this:

```
<Button Margin="5" Click="btnName_Click"  Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource myClass}, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}, Path=Instance.MyAttribute, Mode=OneWay}">
```

notice that the singleton still is a singleton, but we just bypass Silverlight's missing static by not setting the getter as static.

Comment: I'll have to wait till tomorrow to try this out, but this looks like a fine workaround. However, is it considered good practice to not have a static getter on a static member? What is the consequence of not having the getter static?

Comment: not too much.. it's used very often when implementing MVVM in Silverlight, in the ViewModelLocator pattern that was purposed by laurent Bugnion (mvvmlight). It's widely accepted.

Comment: I remembered that in some places in my code I need to access my singleton via a "MyClass.Instance.SomeMethod" call. This will not be possible if the getter is not static.

Comment: you can expose also a static member.. but come to think of it, @vladimir's solution is better than mine.

Answer (score 3):

I have verified the following is working in Silverlight 5:

Keep your class `MyClass` unchanged, then create an property of `MyClass` with the name of `MyClass` in your business UserControl class:

```
public MyClass MyClass
{
    get { return <Namespace>.MyClass.Instance; }
}
```

Then in your business UserControl XAML, do binding like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Visibility Test" Visiblity="{Binding Path=MyClass.MyProperty, Converter={somexmlns:SomeVisiblityConverterIfNecessary}", ElementName="yourBusinessUserControlName"/>
```

Once some where in your application, `MyClass.Instance.MyProperty` (here `MyClass` is the class name) changes the value of `MyProperty`, the above binding will be updated.