# Data binding a string variable of static class to textBlock in Phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7

Here is the C# code

```
public static class Global
{
    public static string Temp 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return temp;
        }
        set
        {
            temp = value;
        }
    }

    public static string temp="100";

}
```

and here is the xaml code of MainPage

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Temp}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="34,47,32,49" Name="textBlockCheck" />
```

I have declared the datacontext in MainPage.cs like this in its constructor:

```
this.DataContext= Global.Temp;
```

But there is nothing being displayed there in the textBlock. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 9):

You can't bind to a static class as binding requires an object instance.

You can, however, bind to static properties of a class.
You could use the following technique if you changed `Global` to not be static but left all it's properties as static.

Assuming:

```
namespace StaticBinding
{
    public class MyStaticClass
    {
        private static string myStaticProperty = "my static text";

        public static string MyStaticProperty
        {
            get { return myStaticProperty; }
            set { myStaticProperty = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if you define the following application resource:

```
.. xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:StaticBinding"

<Application.Resources>
    <myns:MyStaticClass x:Key="MyStaticClassResource" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Then in your page you can simply do the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyStaticProperty, 
                  Source={StaticResource MyStaticClassResource}}" />
```

This will even give you intellisense on the `Path`.

This allows you to bind to "global" static variables and still leave the datacontext free to just contain any model you wish to bind to.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, however, as soon as I add the entry in the <Application.Resources> block, then the application closes immediately upon starting.

Comment: Hi Matt, will the binding receive the update of the static property?  I just tried it, and it turned out it will NOT :-(  Am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply. I think I was using "Notify Property Changed".  However, I found an more elegant solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306064/how-to-bind-to-a-singleton-property-in-silverlight-4/9156409#9156409 . See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not supported to bind to static property

Try to make the class singleton and bind to instance

this could help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/wpf/thread/257a41be-8168-401c-a915-cdc44e195a3f

Answer (score 0):

I think, that

this.Text = Global.Temp

Answer (score 0):

You can use:  `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" />` or `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for help the problem is solved. Actually you create a simple class L

```
public partial class App : Application
{


    //--------------My Class

    private static MyClass _class = null;

    public static MyClass _Class
    {
        get
        {              
            if (_class == null)
                _class = new MyClass();

            return _class;
        }
    }
```

and in the page where you want to bind do this in .cs file's class constructor

```
DataContext = App._Class;
```

and lastly in .xaml version of your file write this to bind

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding value}" Name="textBlockCheck" />
```

where

> value

in Binding is actually the Property of the Class MyClass.
:)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This will work but prevents use of the `DataContext` for binding to the [view]model.