# Binding listview to a property in another class

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I have the following static class

```
static class ContactSettings
{
    static ObservableCollection<Contact> _contactCollection = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

    public static ObservableCollection<Contact> ContactCollection
    {
        get { return _contactCollection; }
    }
}
```

where Contact is a class with Contact.Name, and Contact.Address string properties.

I want to bind the ContactCollection above to a WPF ListView that resides in a Window.

Here's my ListView XAML definition

```
<ListView x:Name="_contactListView" DataContext="{Binding Path=ContactSettings}" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactSettings.ContactCollection}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
         <GridViewColumn Header="Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}" />                                        
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The binding doesn't work.  I am pretty sure the problem is with the 
DataContext and ItemSource properties inside XAML.  I can get the code to work if I move the ContactCollection inside the Window class, and set DataContext to Self.  The problem is I don't how to tell ListView to bind to a collection inside another class.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot bind to a static class as binding requires an instance of a class.

You can try a workaround like this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323052/data-binding-a-string-variable-of-static-class-to-textblock-in-phone-7)